# LTspice `Icrating` of BJTs

Tags: bjt, spice, ltspice

I see LTspice has an `Icrating` parameter for BJTs. As far as I can tell this isn't part of SGP (SPICE Gummel-Poon model) and also not present in other flavors of SPICE. So what is `Icrating` good for? It it used in any way by the program, or is it for user information only? I'm guessing you could for instance script it (say via `.MEAS`) to find if some BJT exceeds its collector current rating, although I haven't seen that done.

[image]

Obviously that determines what goes into the [max] Ic column.

[image]

Is that all there is to it?

Comment: It might be to highlight things in the efficiency report

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I quote the helpfile (section "Q. Bipolar transistor"):

> It is possible to annotate a model with device ratings. This information is displayed in the schematic capture GUI to assist in selecting a device but does not directly impact the electrical behavior in simulation. The following parameters may be specified.
>
> Name   ->  Description   ->  Units
>
> Vceo    ->  Maximum collector-emitter voltage with the base floating -> V
>
> Icrating -> Maximum collector current -> A
>
> mfg -> Name of manufacturer -> -